# SQL Query - Create time series (create series from 2 columns)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, count, multiple-columns

As a n00b in SQL, can you help me out.

In SQL (or Google's BigQuery) current table :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-31 | null |
| null | 2022-01-23 |
| 2009-04-12 | 2022-07-23 |

My query which is wrong:

```
select
count(ColA)   as A,
count(ColB) as B,
FORMAT_DATE('%Y %m', ColA) as month_year,

from myTable
group by month_year
```

so i've got so far :

| month_year | Count A | Count B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12 | 1 | 0 |

the output i'd like to do a simple count, aggregated year month. As you can see i will be missing some counts on col B since we are using the 'array' of dates from ColA.

So how can I make a proper count on both columns combined as the 'aggregate array' for the year month grouping.

i want :

| month_year | "Count" A | "Count" B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-04 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-12 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-07 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m', coalesce(column_a, column_b)) month_year
    , count(column_a) as a
    , count(column_b) as b
from sample_data
group by month_year
```

The coalesce function allows you to return a value that is not null.  As a caveat this solution may not work as expected if both columns have a value for both columns that are in different months.

Comment: Terrific!  If this was helpful please consider upvoting as well.

Comment: what if we do have dates in both columns on different (months) dates? This will occur at a later stage. (think of it as start , stop timestamps)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this  (MS SQL)

[image]

```
   select
    COALESCE((FORMAT ( ColA , 'yyyy-MM' )), (FORMAT ( ColB , 'yyyy-MM' ))) AS month_year,
    count(ColA)   AS [Count A],
    count(ColB) AS [Count B]
    from myTable
    group by ColA,ColB
```

DEMO LINK https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fe2e9995a7040f8aaeecd8339012ee3

Comment: thanks, i did the formatting different: ```    FORMAT_DATE('%Y %m', coalesce(colA,colB) ) as dateArr ```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select format_date('%Y-%m', date(date)) month_year, column 
  from your_table
  unpivot (date for column in (columnA, columnB))
)
pivot (count(*) count for column in ('columnA', 'columnB'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select '2021-12-31' columnA, null columnB union all
  select null,  '2022-01-23' union all
  select '2009-04-12', '2022-07-23'
)
```

output is

[image]